# Gmail Add-on: You do not have permission to call Jdbc.getConnection or UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

In my Gmail Add-on written in Apps Script, I am trying to to connect to an external MySQL using [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

The script contains

```
  var dbUrl = 'xxx';
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, 'xxx', 'xxx');
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from koalas");
```

When it gets executed, I am getting an error message `You do not have permission to call getConnection`.

Similar issue when I am trying to use [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

How to fix it?

Comment: I found that to make the fetch, I need to add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request" in oauthScopes (https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/scopes). Still not sure about JDBC.

Comment: I am not sure if it's just typo, but I can see that your `dbUrl` is not a string. Try to make it a string. Also try as well to change the the single quote to double quote in your string elements. See the documentation for [getConnection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl) as reference. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure I understand. `dbUrl` is a string, its value is in single quotes. Anyway, I put all string literals in double quotes -- still does not work.

Comment: However one thing changed since the morning when I asked the question: now I'm getting "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password" (regardless of single or double quoted strings). When I copy-paste the DB props to a DB client running on my computer, it connects fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the next information in the web link

1. Open the script project.
2. At the left, click Project Settings settings.
3. Select the Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor checkbox.
4. At the left, click Editor code.
5. At the left, click the appsscript.json file.
6. Locate the top-level field labeled oauthScopes. If it's not present, you can add it.
7. The oauthScopes field specifies an array of strings. To set the scopes your project uses, replace the contents of this array with the scopes you want it to use.

For example: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

When found, follow the steps and add this link:

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",

I fixed the same problem with this